# Escaping ' in Microsoft Academic API query

Tags: python, string, escaping, academic-graph, microsoft-academic-graph

I am trying to use the Microsoft Academic API to download the publications of [this author](https://academic.microsoft.com/author/3035197386/publication/search?q=Martin%20Kang%E2%80%99ethe%20Gachukia&qe=Composite(AA.AuId%253D3035197386)&f=&orderBy=0&paperId=3120079032). Since his name contains a ', the API throws an error. I am passing this URL to the API:
[https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Composite(AA.AuN==%27martin kang'ethe gachukia%27)&model=latest&attributes=AA.AuId&count=10&offset=0&subscription-key=YOUR_KEY"](https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=Composite(AA.AuN==%27martin%20kang%27ethe%20gachukia%27)&model=latest&attributes=AA.AuId&count=10&offset=0&subscription-key=YOUR_KEY%22)

When using this url, the ' in the middle of the name is replaced by %27, which leads to an error because the %27 indicate the beginning and end of a query term.

My question is, how do I prevent this behavior? Is there a way I need to escape the apostrophe to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, the query should not include special chars, so you can safely replace the ' char with space in your query.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Replacing the ' with a space however didn't work, but just removing the ' did the job